# In Android Jellybean, how do I share a contact entry with specific fields I choose?

Tags: android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean, google-contacts-api, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I have a phone with an android jellybean 4.3. I am using google contacts in my people app. I would like to share my contact entry to my clients, however, I only want to send them specific entries such as my mobile number and email address only. My own contact entry have a lot of other fields in them such as home address, birthday, etc. which I do not want to send.

When I try sharing a contact entry via Bluetooth, Barcode Scanner, Gmail, etc it sends all of my Info without prompting me to choose which field from the contact I want to share. Is there a way to send only specific fields or do I need another app for that?

Answer (score 0):

You make a new contact that just has the information that you want to share in it.

Comment: but what if i want to share numerous other contacts as well? making a new entry every time isn't really a good solution.